# How to implement this relationship using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

[ERD diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zsyy.png)
PHP code:

```
$insert_address = "insert into address (Street, Town, County, Postcode) values('$street', '$town', '$county', '$postcode')";

$run_address = mysqli_query($con, $insert_address);

$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);


$insert_user = "insert into user (UserIPAddress, Username, Email, Forename, Surname,  Password, UserIcon, AddressID) values('$IP', '$username', '$email', '$firstname', '$secondname', '$password', '$userimage', '$last_id')";

$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $insert_user);

$sel_cart = "select * from cart where IPAddress='$IP'";

$run_cart = mysqli_query($con, $sel_cart);

$check_cart = mysqli_num_rows($run_cart);
```

In order for the AddressID to automatically populate my user table, I need to run the query before I run the insert query for my user table. However, inserting the 'UserID' into the address table requires the insert user query to have been run before the insert address query. I can't run two queries in one, so I deleted the UserID field from my Address table.

However, now I need the user to be able to update the details stored in the database tables. This works fine for the info in the user table, but not for the info in the address table. To combat this, I created a separate html page where the user could update their address, but without the userID I don't know how to get the right address for each user.

I'm up to

```
$get_address = "select * from address where AddressID='$address'";
```

But this obviously doesnt work. 
Without the foreign key UserID I don't know how to make it work.
I've tried sessions but I really don't understand them.

Comment: You don't really need the UserID column in table address, do you? The question is  what kind of relationship this shall be: 1:1, 1:n or n:1 (one user one address, one user multiple addresses, multiple users on one address) or n:n.

Comment: I suppose you want 1:n -> one user can have multiple addresses. So I'd remove the AddressID in table user.

Comment: It seems like you don't need Address.UserId, since you already have User.AddressId. To get the right address for each user, just join on User.AddressId = Address.Id. I suggest you do some studying on the basics of sql and joining.

Comment: Further, you shouldn't be searching by IP to retrieve the cart